# Does Boost geometry have line and line segment intersection?

Tags: c++, boost, geometry, boost-geometry

I have seen example of line segment(s1) and line segment(s2) example but I have not came across line (l) and line segment(s) intersection. Does any one know where I can find one or if there is any.

I tried to use linestring (l)  and segment (s) but I get error when I try to use them as 
 `typedef boost::geometry::model::point<double, 2, boost::geometry::cs::cartesian> boostPoint;`

`std::vector<boostPoint> output;`

`boost::geometry::intersection(line, seg,output);`

Comment: Yes, `intersection` for `segment` and `linestring` doesn't compile, but we know that any segment can be represented by `linestring` so you can use `intersection` for two linestrings objects, in this case code compiles. I know that the use of linestring to represent segment is redundant (`segment` uses *pair* of points, `linestring` uses *vector* to keeps points) but code compiles and works, so use linestrings.

Comment: But aren't line  (line string) and line segment (segment) fundamentally different. Line extend to infinite and segment does not.

Comment: In Boost segment is *finite* line which contains 2 points (start point and end point), it is not considered as *infinite line* while calculating the interesection points. So I think you cannot do the calculations you want (segments treated as inifinite lines).

Comment: @rafix07 it depends on the actual goal (which is not specified in the question). There is, e.g. a distance strategy that uses "projected point" which does use the "extended line" for a segment

Comment: @sehe Yes, you are right as to *projected point* strategy, mabye it would be useful in this case, but OP's question should be more clear.